# How to stop creating new container before deleting old container in ECS?

Tags: amazon-ecs

I have a c5.xlarge machine (4cpu and 8gb ram) , and I have 2 applications where I have given menory_reservation as 7gb for each application's ECS task.

These applications are deployed frequently and what happens is like every time when a new deployment happens its trying to create a new container and since no space is there it creates a new ec2 machine (as auto-scaling is already there), then place the new container over there and then delete this old container

In this way each time a new machine is created and even after deleting the old container ec2 machine is still running for few hours or minutes. Now this is adding up additional cost

Is there any way in ECS to specify that delete the old container before deploying the new container(it is ok if it fails / not available during the deletion and re-creation time)

Answer (score 1):

Please see the ECS Service [Deployment configuration settings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service_definition_parameters.html). By default, ECS is trying to spin up the new service task and make sure it is healthy before shutting down the old service task, to prevent any down-time of your service. To make it shutdown the old task first, before starting the new task, you need to set the Deployment configuration `maximumPercent` to `100` and the `minimumHealthyPercent` to `0`.